# Create postgres table from dictionary in python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, dataset, psycopg2

I'm using the `dataset` package in python to connect to a `postgres` database on my local machine.  After connecting, I run the following code:

```
db = dataset.connect('postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/db')

my_dict = {'Person': ['Joe', 'Lou', 'Kim', 'Tim', 'Emma'], 
           'Age': [40, 37, 13, 8, 3], 
           'Height': ["5'11", "5'6", "5'8", "4'3", "3'0"]}

table = db['new_data']
table.insert(my_dict)
```

This creates a table called `new_data` in my local database, but the results come out like this:

```
 id |             Person             |      Age       |         Height        
----+--------------------------------+----------------+------------------------
  1 |      {Joe,Lou,Kim,Tim,Emma}    | {40,37,13,8,3} | {5'11,5'6,5'8,4'3,3'0}
```

Essentially, all the values of my dictionary item come back on the same row.  This should have a different row from each item, similar to a dataframe.

```
    Person  Age Height
0   Joe     40  5'11
1   Lou     37  5'6
2   Kim     13  5'8
3   Tim     8   4'3
4   Emma    3   3'0
```

I couple things I tried:

I created my dictionary manually `{k:v}`.  This works when I pass that object to insert it into the table, but it makes the rows incorrect like you see above.  I also tried using the `to_dict` function, creating the dictionary from a pandas DataFrame, but I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict'
```

This seems to have something to do with how the `dictionary` item is created when using the `to_dict` function, as the key is the column name, but the values are a nested dictionary, with row indices as the key and the row values as values.

The other thing I tried was created the dictionary using a dictionary comprehension, iterating over the dataframe.  I get the same error as above.  I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: I am typing your code into empty python file. Save. Run. And it just works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all the keys inside your `dict` are of equal length, you can convert your above dictionary to the below form.

```
[{'Person': 'Joe', 'Age': 40, 'Height': "5'11"},
 {'Person': 'Lou', 'Age': 37, 'Height': "5'6"},
 {'Person': 'Kim', 'Age': 13, 'Height': "5'8"},
 {'Person': 'Tim', 'Age': 8, 'Height': "4'3"},
 {'Person': 'Emma', 'Age': 3, 'Height': "3'0"}]
```

Now you can iterate and insert each `dict` object into your table as shown below,

```
for pos, val in enumerate(my_dict['Person']):
    table.insert({'Person': val, 'Age': my_dict['Age'][pos], 'Height': my_dict['Height'][pos]})
```